# Perl Hash is initialised incorrectly when accessing it's undefined value

Tags: perl

I've below sample code.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
my $var=undef;
warn Dumper($var);
if ( $var->{CHECK}->{CHOKE} )
{
    print "Success\n";
}
else
{
    print "Failure\n";
}
warn Dumper($var);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = undef;
Failure
$VAR1 = {
          'CHECK' => {}
        };
```

Initially, the `$var` is undefined. Inside the `if` clause,
I'm trying to access the value of `{CHOKE}` through `{CHECK}` through `$var`.

The `if` Loop fails correctly as expected. But now the value of `$var` contains value (though it's null) for `{CHECK}`.

Is this a bug in Perl? If this expected behaviour, please help me in understanding this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is a feature called [autovivification](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary#autovivification), which automatically creates the sublevel of your data structure when you try to access a higher level.

So when you do

```
if ( $var->{CHECK}->{CHOKE} )
```

then `$var->{CHECK}` is created.

Answer (score 2):

The autovivification feature means that

```perl
$x->{y}
```

is effectively equivalent to

```perl
( $x //= {} )->{y}
```

When `$x` is undef and you treat it as a hash reference, a hash gets created and a reference to the hash assigned to `$x`.

Using [`no autovivification;`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autovivification) will curtail this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Other's have already shown that this is expected autovivification behavior. If you don't want this, you can turn that feature off, but you can also use a guard to check for the key before you go deeper:

```
if( exists $var->{CHECK} ) { ... }
```

You might even combine those:

```
if( exists $var->{CHECK} and exists $var->{CHECK}{CHOKE} ) { ... }
```